# unexpected behaviour of `global` variables in Python

Tags: python

```
prev, prev_re = '', (None) # these are globals

def find(h, p='', re=None):
    print h, p, re
    #global prev, prev_re
    if p == '' and prev == h: return prev_re
    prev, prev_re = h, re
    return re
print find ("abc")
```

results in this error:

```
    if p == '' and prev == h: return prev_re
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prev' referenced before assignment
$
```

**But** if I comment the before last line of `find`,

```
prev, prev_re = '', (None)

def find(h, p='', re=None):
    print h, p, re
    #global prev, prev_re
    if p == '' and prev == h: return prev_re
    #prev, prev_re = h, re
    return re
print find ("abc")
```

the code runs correctly, as expected, without error.

My questions are why in the first case it does not find the global variable  `prev`, and why in the second case it does find the global variable in the `if`-condition ?

edit: please help me understand the details of the structure of environments, to understand why the interpretor cannot find the variable.

Comment: I've came across this behavior before, and from I made out I think by making an assignment to the global variables and not explicitly mark them out as globals in the function, you created new local variables, which you used before you assigned them.

Comment: There is no `if pre == '' and prev == h: return prev_re` in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`global` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) makes a global variable available in the scope of a function. If you don't declare something global, Python has no way to know that you are referring to a global vs. creating a new local.

The error you're getting just means that Python has recognized you're using a variable before setting it; you'd get the same error even if the global variables weren't defined at all.

Comment: Thanks. I saw in docs: `Programmer’s note: the global is a directive to the parser`.

Answer (score 7):

### Problem and solution

As MAK has mentioned, `prev` is treated as local because you assign value to it (after you check the value). The solution is to explicitly state these two variables as global:

```py
prev, prev_re = '', (None) # these are globals

def find(h, p='', re=None):
    global prev, prev_re
    print h, p, re
    #global prev, prev_re  # basically what you have done before commenting this
    if p == '' and prev == h: return prev_re
    prev, prev_re = h, re
    return re
print find ("abc")
```

### Answers to your questions

> why in the first case it does not find the global variable prev

It finds it, but then it finds the assignment that was not preceded by `global` statement. Thus the variable is treated as *local*. Uncomment the line with `global` and it will be fixed. Or use different variables for local assignments. You could also save the value as an attribute of the function (functions are objects too!).

> why in the second case it does find the global variable in the if-condition

It treats it as global (because you only read it and you do not define it within the function, so it is not shadowed by local variable).

### More reading

You asked for the place in the documentation when this behaviour is mentioned. I did not find any place where this is explicitly stated what the error means and why this specific case happens, but there is [very good explanation of the execution model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) that may be sufficient:

> **If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the current block. This can lead to errors when a name is used within a block before it is bound.** ***This rule is subtle. Python lacks declarations and allows name binding operations to occur anywhere within a code block. The local variables of a code block can be determined by scanning the entire text of the block for name binding operations.***
>
> If the global statement occurs within a block, all uses of the name specified in the statement refer to the binding of that name in the top-level namespace. Names are resolved in the top-level namespace by searching the global namespace, i.e. the namespace of the module containing the code block, and the builtins namespace, the namespace of the module `__builtin__`. The global namespace is searched first. If the name is not found there, the builtins namespace is searched. **The `global` statement must precede all uses of the name**.

So basically:

- if the assignments occurs within specific function, the variable is treated as *local*, unless...
- if the uses of the variable are preceded by `global` statement, the variable is treated as *local*,
- if there is no assignment, the variable is first looked up in the local namespace, then global one, then it is searched for in `__builtin__` module,

Please also note that Python 3 has `nonlocal` statement that tells interpreter that the variable is from the outer scope (not the current one, but not necessarily the global one).

Comment: I think I understand -- if an assignment takes place to a variable, the compiler will treat the variable as local... Can you show me the place in the Python's docs where this fact is explained, please ?

Comment: @alinsoar: Done. Please see the updated version of the answer plus short summary

Comment: @Tadeck: See [4.1 Naming and binding](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html?highlight=local#naming-and-binding) in the docs.

Comment: @Tadeck: It's crucial to notice the _anywhere_ in "occurs anywhere within a code block" because it means it has nothing to do with the order that the statements occur or are "executed" in.

Comment: Thank you all . The problem is generated by the parser, as I finally found in the documentation . The same problem does not take place if you build the function as a string and call 'eval' . It was nice to receive such a quick response .

Comment: @martineau: Your "_See 4.1 Naming and binding in the docs_" points exactly to the same place I have linked in my answer 10 minutes earlier ;) The quote goes directly from there. Please also read my summary, that says what I think you are trying to say. Also order _does_ matter, as OP saw - assignment after the comparison raised `UnboundLocalError`, while changing this order would not result in such exception.

Comment: @Tadeck: I didn't include the  first of the quote, namely the "If a name binding operation occurs _anywhere_ within a code block, ..." and I think this part of your summary, "if the uses of the variable are preceded by global statement" in incorrect. Where the `global` statement is doesn't matter, the docs just say "If the global statement occurs within a block" which also means anywhere I believe.

Comment: @martineau: Wrong, at least because such step would result in warning (about assignment before global declaration). And the interpretation of warnings is a different topic (they may be turned into exceptions or be ignored, depending on what the programmer really wants to achieve). In other words: bad things will happen and such things (assignments before global statements) should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

You did not declare `prev` as global. If you only ever do read actions on the variable, python will trybto treat the variable as global. However, because you do an assignment, python detects this and makes `prev` a local variable.

See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements for more information. Specifically, the part that states the following:

> Assignment of an object to a single target is recursively defined as
>   follows.
>
> If the target is an identifier (name):
>
> - If the name does not occur in a global statement in the current code
>     block: the name is bound to the object in the current local namespace.
> - Otherwise: the name is bound to the object in the current global
>     namespace.

If you intend for a variable name to reference a global, you should declare it as global with the `global` statement.

Comment: can you show me in python's docs where this is written, please?

Answer (score 2):

IINM, the Python interpreter detects that the variable is assigned to later in the function, and so treats it as a local.

A workaround would be to use a class and have prev and prev_re as instance variables of the class.

Comment: That was expectedd, but I want details about the allocations of environments.

Comment: What means `to assign later` ? I came from the direction of c/lisp, and never heard about this concept.

Comment: @alinsoar It means that you put `prev_re = re` after `return prev_re`, so Python thought that you were trying to use the local variable `prev_re` before you declared it. (see Tadeck's answer for more info)